# How do I get the query string of a html file using express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to get the query string of my html file.

Here is how my files are laid out

Website:

> > public > Index.html, query.html
>
> Script.js
>
> Server.js

---

Here is the code in server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query);
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Here is the code in query.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Query</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/query.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="sign-in">
            <form id="form" onSubmit="WriteToFile(this)">
                <div class="together">
                    <h1>
                        Username:
                    </h1>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
                </div>
                <div class="together">
                    <h1>
                        Email:
                    </h1>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
                </div>
                <div class="together">
                    <h1>
                        Password:
                    </h1>
                    <input minlength="4" type="password" name="password" id="password">
                </div>
                <div class="together">
                    <h1>
                        Confirm Password:
                    </h1>
                    <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword">
                </div>
                <div class="together">
                    <button type="submit" method="post" id="submit" name="submit" value="true">
                        Create new account!
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Index.html contains a link that goes to query.html

When I go to localhost:3000,
for whatever reason, the terminal is not logging anything

I have a style folder with css files, but that's not important

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your question isn't really clear, first off, you can't server.js shouldn't be able to get the query string because it's the server. add a `script` tag to the query.html file referencing script.js... you should be good from there onwards

Answer (score 0):

I tried sending the file instead of just using the file. I sent the file to `/query`. This worked for me

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));



app.get('/query, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/query.html')); //I sent the file to /query
    console.log(req.query);
})

app.listen(3000)
```